# Chrome extension, drawing canvas in the window, not document

Tags: google-chrome-extension, html5-canvas

How to draw a line of shoot on Canvas HTML5  or other plugin of Chrome extension, for a web page of game, which is displayed to the user, **but the object canvas must not appear in the document DOM elements**.

```
alert(canvas.length) // 0
```

It's possible?, thanks

Comment: That's not possible. What exactely do you want? Why should the canvas not show up in the document?

Comment: It was obvious that you do not want to see a `<canvas>` element in the document. This is not possible, so you need to share more details about the application before a reasonable alternative can be given. 1. What is the purpose of the canvas? 2. Why should it not be visible through `document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");`?

Comment: Web page should not see an alteration of the document.
 The player is in a place, and opponent in other place in pixels {x,y}, a line of shot is showing where the user pointed to opponent. 
 I used algorithms parabolic motion  to create this line in canvas. The game web should not detect this line. Thanks

Comment: The first step is to not display the canvas element itself, but serialize the image data and show the image via a `data:image/....;base64,...` url (in a `<img>` element, or `background-image` CSS property).

Show this image in a layer over the page, using the `position`, `top`, `left`, `width` and `height` CSS attributes. Finally, add **`pointer-events: none;`** to your style so that the layer does not interfere with page interaction. But, if the owner is really determined to catch your cheating method, he'll be able to do it by writing highly specific detection methods.

Comment: Thanks for your answer :).
I did not know of that property, but the owner can detect dom objects via javascript.
I have seen the extension Google Chat, that interacts  above the window browser (no are notifications), but i do not know what methods or plugins are used.
If this is possible, then there must be a way to draw on canvas with a plugin (Chrome extensions), above the window browser

Comment: [Google Chat](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/chat-for-google/nckgahadagoaajjgafhacjanaoiihapd) uses a [NPAPI](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/npapi.html) plugin.